# Script cuota de disco

Tags: script, vbscript

Tengo un script que a los nuevos usuarios les crea una carpeta cuando inician sesión por primera vez:

```
@echo off 
IF exist %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%USERNAME% 
     (echo %USERNAME% exists) 
ELSE 
     (mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%USERNAME% && echo %USERNAME% created)
```

Quisiera saber si se puede automatizar un poco más y añadirle que asigne ademas una cuota de disco.

```
@echo off 
IF exist %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%USERNAME% ( echo %USERNAME% exists ) ELSE ( mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%USERNAME% && echo %USERNAME% created)

colDiskQuotas.Initialize "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%USERNAME%", True

set objUser = colDiskQuotas.FindUser("%USERNAME%")
objUser.QuotaLimit = 50000000
```

Comment: Buenas Alberto, echale un vistazo a [éste enlace](https://www.activexperts.com/admin/vbscript-collection/disk/quotas/), aqui tienes fragmentos para añadir Disk Quota al usuario en cuestión con vbscript.

Comment: No se si sería más o menos así